# Clipboard obfuscation/deobfuscation - encountering fatal error

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, clipboard, fatal-error, office-addins

I'm writing a C# Word 2013 Add-in that obfuscates the clipboard contents if the content being copied is within a managed Word application.

I have a few questions.

1. I've ran into a FatalExecutionEngineError when attempting to call Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData() if the Data Format is "EnhancedMetaFile". Apparently, from my research, this is a known issue. The most relevant question I've found is from 2007, is the recommended solution still to use the Clipboard APIs instead of the built-in .NET Clipboard library? References below with code snippet.

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/689572-fatalexecutionengineerror-calling-clipboard-getdataobject-getdata-enhancedmetafile

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323530

```
public static void ClipboardEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDataObject contentObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    if (contentObj != null)
    {
        foreach (string dataFormat in contentObj.GetFormats())
        {
            try
            {
                object data = contentObj.GetData(dataFormat); // throws here
                object obfuscatedData = Obfuscate(data);
                contentObj.SetData(dataFormat, obfuscatedData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
            }
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(contentObj);
    }
}
```

2. I need to differentiate between a copy operation and my own modification to the clibpoard. I currently have a event watcher on the API method AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd), but this informs me every time the clipboard changes, including when I obfuscate the data and add it to the clipboard, therefore I basically end up in a infinite loop. How can I differentiate between a copy operation and my own modifications to the clipboard contents?
3. If the contents of the clipboard are obfuscated, and I detect a paste of obfuscated data using my Add-in, I want to deobfuscate the data and show it as it would normally appear. How do I detect the paste and deobfuscate before the paste actually happens? Can I just override the following method in my Add-in?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649038(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know #1.

2 - add another data format to the clipboard. Call it CF_Clipboard_Obfuscated.  Register it.  When you detect clipboard updates, see if that format is present. If it is, then you know you're hearing your own "echo", and ignore it.

3 - use Delayed Rendering.

As an extension of 2, you could just support the "Clipboard Viewer Ignore" flag as described here (article by me):[Ignoring Clipboard Updates with the CF_CLIPBOARD_VIEWER_IGNORE Clipboard Format](http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows/ignoring-clipboard-updates-with-the-cf_clipboard_viewer_ignore-clipboard-format)

Comment: #2 - I add a new data format, but Word copies several different data formats to the clipboard on a copy. I need to provide obfuscation for the clipboard content for all data formats, not just my own.

#3 - I've heard of delayed rendering, I'll have to do a bit more research there. Thanks.

Comment: You can update the clipboard without wiping it out, thereby adding your new format but keeping everything else intact.  Usually, you'd open, clear, update, close.  Just skip the CLEAR step.

Comment: Delayed Rendering is explained in the MSDN doc.

Comment: It I kept everything else on the clipboard intact, then it would be able to be pasted anywhere without obfuscation, correct? That's what I'm trying to prevent. This is a security mechanism inside my managed applications.

Comment: Ok, then you DO want to clear.  Open, clear, add your obfuscated versions of  thee data, add your extra flag format, close.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks! Also, for delayed rendering, how would I make this work? Would I push the null value for every data format on the clipboard, then push obfuscated or not obfuscated data when I receive a WM_RENDERFORMAT event?

Comment: Yes. You push nulls, then if/when the data is requested, provide the obfuscated version of the data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. Seems like this is really meant to be done in C++ land. Attempts in C# haven't gone too well.